# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $accountSid ]] in class Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken

Tags: twilio-php

I am trying to implement twilio chat using laravel. I have follow tutorial and try the source from github, https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twiliochat-laravel. Works well in desktop, but when moving to linux enviroment, it shows error:

```
(1/1) BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $accountSid ]] in class Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken
```

The linux environment is using Laravel/Lumen 5.8.4
Here's the steps I have done :

composer require twilio/sdk

in routes/web.php :

```
//twilio
$router->group(['prefix' => 'twilio'], function() use ($router){
   $router->post('/token',['uses' => 'TwilioController@generate','as' => 'token-generate']);
});
```

in app/Http/Controller :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\ChatGrant;

class TwilioController extends Controller
{
    public function generate(Request $request, AccessToken $accessToken, ChatGrant $chatGrant)
    {
        var_dump('test aja');
        exit;
        $appName = "allsmartchat";
        $deviceId = $request->input("device");
        $identity = $request->input("identity");

        $TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID = 'IS****'; //my SID

        $endpointId = $appName . ":" . $identity . ":" . $deviceId;

        $accessToken->setIdentity($identity);

        $chatGrant->setServiceSid($TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID);
        $chatGrant->setEndpointId($endpointId);

        $accessToken->addGrant($chatGrant);
        $response = array(
            'identity' => $identity,
            'token' => $accessToken->toJWT()
        );

        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

in app/Providers/TwilioAccessProvider.php :

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;

class TwilioAccessTokenProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            AccessToken::class, function ($app) {
                $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'AC***';
                $TWILIO_API_KEY = 'SK***';
                $TWILIO_API_SECRET = '***';
                $token = new AccessToken(
                    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
                    $TWILIO_API_KEY,
                    $TWILIO_API_SECRET,
                    3600
                );
                return $token;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I use postman to get the token value, in localhost, it produces token :

```
{
    "identity": null,
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTS2E4OGQ2ZjVjNTEyNTkzMWMxMmYxYmFiYmFiZWY4MTU0LTE1NjM0MzkzOTQiLCJpc3MiOiJTS2E4OGQ2ZjVjNTEyNTkzMWMxMmYxYmFiYmFiZWY4MTU0Iiwic3ViIjoiQUFBQUNjZjMyMTdkNWU3NTEwMzA4ZjM2ZDZlYzNhZmJkOGNiZCIsImV4cCI6MTU2MzQ0Mjk5NCwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImNoYXQiOnsic2VydmljZV9zaWQiOiJJU2JjM2Y3N2Y2MjEzYjQ3MzliZTBlYTJiOTRiZTc4OWRmIiwiZW5kcG9pbnRfaWQiOiJUd2lsaW9DaGF0OjoifX19.OuAjJs_KGz-J_WTPlrCfAV_bjKmKCvSOTzj_ZGU0mUA"
}
```

but in server, it shows error :

```
(1/1) BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $accountSid ]] in class Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken

in Container.php line 973
at Container->unresolvablePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter))
in Container.php line 911
at Container->resolvePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter))
in Container.php line 852
at Container->resolveDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter)))
in Container.php line 818
at Container->build('Twilio\\Jwt\\AccessToken')
in Container.php line 667
at Container->resolve('Twilio\\Jwt\\AccessToken', array())
in Container.php line 615
at Container->make('Twilio\\Jwt\\AccessToken', array())
in Application.php line 260
at Application->make('Twilio\\Jwt\\AccessToken')
in BoundMethod.php line 167
at BoundMethod::addDependencyForCallParameter(object(Application), object(ReflectionParameter), array(), array(object(Request)))
in BoundMethod.php line 121
at BoundMethod::getMethodDependencies(object(Application), array(object(TwilioController), 'generate'), array())
in BoundMethod.php line 32
at BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
in BoundMethod.php line 90
at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(TwilioController), 'generate'), object(Closure))
in BoundMethod.php line 34
at BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(TwilioController), 'generate'), array(), null)
in Container.php line 576
at Container->call(array(object(TwilioController), 'generate'), array())
in RoutesRequests.php line 376
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(TwilioController), 'generate'), array())
in RoutesRequests.php line 342
at Application->callLumenController(object(TwilioController), 'generate', array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\TwilioController@generate', 'as' => 'token-generate'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php line 316
at Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\TwilioController@generate', 'as' => 'token-generate'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php line 278
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\TwilioController@generate', 'as' => 'token-generate'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php line 263
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\TwilioController@generate', 'as' => 'token-generate'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php line 165
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(object(Request))
in RoutesRequests.php line 416
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php line 171
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php line 108
at Application->run()
in index.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved,

you need to register service in bootstrap/app.php

```
   $app->register(App\Providers\TwilioAccessTokenProvider::class);
   $app->register(App\Providers\TwilioChatGrantProvider::class);
```

also in laravel, you need to register service in config/app.php

```
App\Providers\TwilioAccessTokenProvider::class,
App\Providers\TwilioChatGrantProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution is ok but also you can add this code in the App Provider it will definately work
First include the class

```
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;

        $this->app->bind(
            AccessToken::class,
            function ($app) {
                $accountSid = config('services.twilio')['accountSid'];
                $apiKey = config('services.twilio')['apiKey'];
                $apiSecret = config('services.twilio')['apiSecret'];

                return new AccessToken($accountSid, $apiKey, $apiSecret, 3600, 'identity');
            }
        );
```